# Simulate data around existing data in r

Tags: r, simulation

I have been working at this for sometime, surfing StackExchange and any other R webpage I can find without any luck.

I am trying to simulate data to essentially recreate the attached figure with simulated data. I generated this figure using point data I pulled from the original graph in a publication

> Gilmour CC, Henry EA (1991) Mercury methylation in aquatic systems
>   affected by acid deposition. Environmental pollution 71:131–169

and was wondering if their is a relatively easy way to generate data along/around the uni-modal line below that will have both an "x" and "y" component?

[image: Hypothetical sulfate and mercury methylation relationship (Gilmour and Henry 1991).]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the actual function?

Comment: Are you trying to simulate points *on* the curve or points *near* the curve? If the first, how do you want them distributed along the curve? If the second, what should the marginal distributions look like? Is there error in the x or the y variate, or both, and of what size(s)? If both have errors, how are the errors related? Are the points $(x_i,y_i)$ and $(x_j,y_j)$ to be independent or related?

Comment: Gung and Glen_b, Thanks for your follow-up questions. I am never sure how much to include. No, there is no real function this is a hypothetical relationship. Which make this alot more difficult (I think). I was thinking of simulating data around the line, with some degree of error so that I can run a spline (or lowess) through the "data cloud" and  generate a similar line. Therefore both x and y should have errors but they unrelated errors since they are two different "measurements". Also  the points are independent.

Answer (score 1):

After some digging through the inter-webs and consulting some colleges I think I found an adequate work around. Below are some blocks of code walking through the simulation.

```
#Import data i.e. 
Goldi=read.csv("somefile.csv")
head(Goldi)
    log(x)      Y         x       x.mgL
1 0.1162878  8.252017  1.307037 0.1255278
2 0.2857120 17.881287  1.930688 0.1854232
3 ...   
4 ...
seqx=c(seq(from=min(Goldi$x.mgL),to=10,length.out=200),
   seq(from=10,to=500,length.out=200),seq(from=500,to=max(Goldi$x.mgL),length.out=200))
z=with(Goldi,approx(x=x.mgL, y=Y, xout=seqx, method = "linear"))

#Loop to generate data along the line
set.seed(1);
a=5;
res=numeric();
for (i in 1:length(z$x)){
   b=(a/(z$y/100)[i])-a
   tmp=cbind(z$x[i],100*rbeta(1,a,b))
res=rbind(res,tmp)
};
```

Beta distribution was used for the Y-variable since the value is a proportion (or percentage) and is more appropriate than a normal distribution(or any other). Hope this helps anyone in the future. Behold the power of the loop!!